# Is there any reason to focus on few weapon skills?

Tags: borderlands

I've been trying out the chars in BL 1 and am sticking to Lilith. Seeing as you can be more proficient at certain weapons, I'm wondering - can you spread yourself too thin if you swap between a large variety of weapons?

Comment: I think that depends upon how long you intend to play for as well as how you like to play. 3,060,000 is not a small amount of XP to reach the cap of 50 and if you don't like using the other weapons, you don't really need to. There's nothing forcing you to try out multiple weapon types (although it helps in some places like Moxxi's) so it's not like you have to spread yourself out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annoyingly enough, you can quite easily gain "general" XP (which raises your level) much faster than your individual weapon proficiencies. If you evenly switch between weapons you might not notice a huge difference, but what WILL be noticeable is if you neglect a certain weapon type and suddenly try to use it. A weapon with significantly lower proficiency will perform noticeably worse, which can cause a vicious cycle of you avoiding using that weapon, which means it won't gain proficiency.

If you really enjoy using all the weapons I'm not sure I would recommend deliberately not using some weapons in order to boost specific ones because of that effect; if you focus on weapons, they WILL grow faster and it will be noticeable, but you will make those other weapon types MUCH harder to use later on.

If you plan to play though playthrough 2 and all DLC, I actually *recommend* that you spread yourself thin to keep all weapon proficiency nearly even, because once you cap out a weapon (50 is the max level for weapons, even though the player level cap is 69 with the General Knoxx DLC) all weapon XP earned while using that gun goes to complete waste.

tl;dr the game will be a bit easier midgame if you focus on just a few weapons, but if you plan to play playthrough 2 and all DLCs and hunt for loot, you'll find you have much more flexibility if you spread around weapon experience.

Comment: The gains from weapon proficiency boosts aren't that significant and, since it's based on XP anyway, a quick boss fight worth an adequate amount of XP with your non-proficient weapon equipped when landing the kill will quickly gain multiple proficiency levels for that weapon, balancing out proficiency rather easily. There's really no problem focusing and then spreading out later because it allows you to boost your lower proficiencies with the aid of your higher ones as long as you switch weapon for the kill or use skills etc to get the kills.

Comment: @skovacs1 the accuracy difference can be pretty noticeable on some guns. Just looking at the numbers (damage especially) it doesn't seem super significant, but it's definitely enough that I could *feel* when I switched to a gun of a type with lower proficiency.

Comment: Its worth noting that characters in BL1 are also preferential to certain weapon types - you'll earn more XP with Snipers and Pistols as Mordecai for example. There was a question here on Arqade about it but I can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: @Robotnik really? Is that a % boost, or just circumstantial because Mordecai kills better with Snipers due to abilities focusing on them?

Comment: @BenBrocka IIRC there was an answer somewhere on this site that covers it, but I can't find it. If I do, I'll link it here

Comment: @BenBrocka - I can't find the answer anywhere (or maybe I'm dreaming) but here's a [thread on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/942810-borderlands/51947343) that seems to confirm that you level up your character's 'preferred weapons' faster than others (although not in a game-changing way)